# Issue on using "scrolling text" module in Joomla

Tags: module, joomla2.5, horizontal-scrolling

I have downloaded and installed various module for scrolling text horizontally using [these](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/19059) [websites](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/5866).

After I created new module and point out the position of that module, I can view that module in my web page. The text didn't appear because I didn't mention it in my module.

In Both of those modules, I couldn't find out that where have to I place the text to be scrolled in that particular modules?

I have searched a lot. But I couldn't get anything.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of using any other modules for scrolling the text.

I used `Custom HTML` as menu type and write the code on editor.

The steps I have done as below:

1. Go to site -> Global configuration -> `set Editor-None in default editor`
2. Go to Extension-> module Manager -> New -> `select the module type as Custom HTML`
3. Copy the html code for scrolling text and Paste it in the `text part` and save the module.

Check your site. Now, your site is having the scrolling text. Then, You can change the Editor as before.

Answer (score 0):

These extensions display text from articles. So all you have to do is simpley:

1. Create a category in the Content Manager
2. Create some articles and assign them to your newly created category
3. In the Module settings, there will be an option to choose which category you wish to display the articles from, simply select your category

Hope this helps

Comment: I've created new articles and assigned to newly created category and selected this category in module setting option. But, the content of the article is not showing in web page.

Comment: can you please provide a link to the page that contains the module? It could be due to multiple issues?

Comment: i am using this module only http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/19059

Comment: Yes, but can you provide a link to *your* site, so I can have a look and possibley see what's going wrong?

Comment: oh sorry.. I am using it in my localsite.

Comment: In that case I can't really be of much more help without seeing the site, sorry